# How to install TuxOnIce on Debian Stretch?

Tags: debian, hibernate

I want to install TuxOnIce on my Debian/Windows dual-boot Laptop because I can't get `pm-hibernate` to work properly. Following some [tutorials](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/tuxonice-revolutionise-the-way-you-start-your-linux-system.html), I have done the following things:

Added the TuxOnIce ppa: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tuxonice/ppa`. It seems to work, but after confirming with enter I get the following error:

```
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp2dbcfl9z/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmp2dbcfl9z/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key DAC45EC9DEC8FAAC: public key "Launchpad PPA for TuxOnIce" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func
    func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 386, in add_key
    return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 273, in add_ppa_signing_key
    cleanup(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 234, in cleanup
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 480, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 438, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 436, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(name, dir_fd=topfd)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S.gpg-agent.ssh'
```

Updating with `sudo apt-get update` now shows a list of items that is way longer than before. Most of them start with `http://ppa.launchpad.net/tuxonice/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main` which is curious because I don't have Ubuntu and I have read that Ubuntu packages are not really compatible with Debian. Some links get a 404 error, but most of them work. Again, the output ends with some error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tuxonice/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tuxonice/ppa/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Install the application with `sudo apt-get install tuxonice-userui linux-generic-tuxonice linux-headers-generic-tuxonice`. The package `tuxonice-userui` is already installed, but it can't find the other ones:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-generic-tuxonice
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-generic-tuxonice
```

Comment: Hibernate features should be available by default on Debian 9, and you should be able to hibernate using the regular Gnome menus or keyboard shortcuts.  Is there some reason that's leading you to believe you need to install extra software in order to support hibernation?

Comment: Also more info here: https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation

Comment: Sadly, the default hibernate under Debian does not work, the system always freezes with a black screen when resuming. I already had this problem under Ubuntu on that same machine and TuxOnIce solved it, so I thought I could try this again under Debian. I don't care _how_, I just want some working hibernate. The documentation you linked hasn't been updated to Stretch too by the way

Comment: TuxOnIce : `# apt-get install tuxonice-userui` https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=tuxonice

Comment: @Knud Larsen Already done. But I can't find any command or application to use that package

Comment: The `tuxonice-userui` package wires TuxOnIce into Debian 9's normal sleep/hibernate framework, so all Debian 9's normal ways to hibernate should then use TuxOnIce if it's actually usable. But to make it usable, you'll need the TuxOnIce kernel patch, and there is no pre-packaged DKMS version of the patch in Debian 9, so you'll have to build your own TuxOnIce-patched kernel.